# How to launch TensorFlow Shell shown in XLA Demo

Tags: tensorflow

In the recent video "XLA: TensorFlow, Compiled!" from the 2017 TensorFlow Dev Summit, the presenter shows a shell that resembles iPython and is able to view the JIT'ed assembly:
https://youtu.be/kAOanJczHA0?t=2m32s

I'm trying to recreate the demo so I can display the generated assembly for some other sample code.

I assume the shell is just a wrapper that imports TensorFlow and drops to a iPython shell?
I tried launching a script such as:

```
$ TF_XLA_FLAGS=--xla_dump_assembly=true python mnist_softmax_xla.py
```

and dropping to a shell with:

```
import IPython; IPython.embed()
```

But when I attempt to recreate the code snippet in the demo the assembly isn't displayed. Can anyone help reproduce it?

Thanks!

Comment: I think that is an internal tool that they have. I was looking in the source code to find those commands and could not find any reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Support for "vmodule" logging [just landed in open source TensorFlow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/072b0c9c552837a97c967963628b3c30951388f9), so it's possible to enable logging in specific translation units to see the assembly. Open source TensorFlow doesn't generally use flags, so instead there are some environment variables for controlling some of this debug-oriented behavior. I just built at head and ran on a GCE VM:

`cdleary@instance-1:~/tensorflow$ TF_CPP_VMODULE=gpu_compiler=3 bazel-bin/tensorflow/compiler/xla/tests/while_test_gpu`

And that spits out, as in the video, the PTX (virtual) assembly:

`2017-08-05 05:45:07.030245: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/gpu/gpu_compiler.cc:349] .version 4.2
2017-08-05 05:45:07.030252: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/gpu/gpu_compiler.cc:349] .target sm_37
2017-08-05 05:45:07.030257: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/gpu/gpu_compiler.cc:349] .address_size 64
2017-08-05 05:45:07.030263: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/gpu/gpu_compiler.cc:349] 
2017-08-05 05:45:07.030269: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/gpu/gpu_compiler.cc:349]  // .globl   _greater_than
2017-08-05 05:45:07.030275: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/gpu/gpu_compiler.cc:349] 
2017-08-05 05:45:07.030281: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/gpu/gpu_compiler.cc:349] .visible .entry _greater_than(
2017-08-05 05:45:07.030293: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/gpu/gpu_compiler.cc:349]  .param .u64 _greater_than_param_0,
2017-08-05 05:45:07.030300: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/gpu/gpu_compiler.cc:349]  .param .u64 _greater_than_param_1
[snip]`

Similarly, for CPU:

`cdleary@instance-1:~/tensorflow$ TF_CPP_VMODULE=compiler_functor=3 bazel-bin/tensorflow/compiler/xla/tests/while_test_cpu`

Produces:

`[snip]
2017-08-05 05:49:43.819213: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/cpu/compiler_functor.cc:121] NestedWhileWithScalarResult.v2:
2017-08-05 05:49:43.819244: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/cpu/compiler_functor.cc:121] 0x00000000   movq    (%rcx), %rax
2017-08-05 05:49:43.819256: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/cpu/compiler_functor.cc:121] 0x00000003   movl    $0, (%rax)
2017-08-05 05:49:43.819263: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/cpu/compiler_functor.cc:121] 0x00000009   movq    8(%rcx), %rcx
2017-08-05 05:49:43.819284: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/cpu/compiler_functor.cc:121] 0x0000000d   nopl    (%rax)
2017-08-05 05:49:43.819299: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/cpu/compiler_functor.cc:121] 0x00000010   movq    %rcx, 16(%rcx)
2017-08-05 05:49:43.819314: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/cpu/compiler_functor.cc:121] 0x00000014   movq    %rax, 24(%rcx)
[snip]`

HTH!

Answer (score 1):

You're right that the shell is just a wrapper that imports TensorFlow and drops into an iPython shell.

Note that at the moment, in order to get a version of TensorFlow that supports XLA, you need to compile TensorFlow from source.  When you run ./configure you'll be asked whether to enable XLA, and you need to respond Y (yes).

We're working hard to enable XLA by default, but that's what's necessary at the moment.  Hope this helps!